# Inter-networking book for windows and Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have searched some books on inter-networking and most of those books describe theoretical approach. I want to make a small office network and I have never configured it before. So I need such a book which discuss practical approaches of inter-networking for window and Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! When you are new to an online community, it's polite to read the [faq] in its entirety. Once you've done this, you'll understand why this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format.

Comment: Well I guess, I know stack-exchange sites are only for problem solving. So can I contact u by your email address to get answer of my question?????

Comment: If you feel the need to contact me, I can refer you to consultants that I know that have reasonable hourly rates. I, however, do not consult, so I wouldn't assist you.

Comment: It depends on how do you want to build your architecture. Is it supposed to be a Samba domain, where only some workstations run Windows or do you want to connect Linux workstations to Active Directory domain where servers and most workstations run Windows?

Comment: What are your needs? You need to give some more details. Do you need Server-based Authentification, do you DNS, DHCP... so far we know close to nothing about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @juwi thnx....I meant what you have said. I want to configure DNS, DHCP...

Answer (score 1):

[Using Samba](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007690.do) comes to mind. While reading it you will naturally have a lot of questions for which Google, SF and newsgroups will help.